# Apply double filter in visual basic (on a database)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

As I am new to this language, The problem is as follows;

I created a database with rental properties. Some of the properties share the same streetname but, ofcourse, have a different house number.
I created a view so that the addresses and tentants are put together.

it looks something like this:

```
address    |  number | roomnumber |  zipcode | tenant|
homestreet      1          2         12345ab   john
homestreet      2          4         12345ab   jane
```

Now i wanted to add a search bar, with "live searching" so thats why I put it on `"textbox2_TextChanged"`

it looks like this:

```
Me.tenant_QueryBindingSource.Filter = "address like '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'"
```

The goal now is to search for 1 property, lets say `homestreet 2`, with `TextBox1.Text` being `Homestreet` and `TextBox2.Text` being `2`.

in short:

How can I make it that it filters out the address, in this case `homestreet`, and from the list that shows up, filter out number 2. so that I only see

```
address    |  number | roomnumber |  zipcode | tenant|
homestreet      2          4         12345ab   jane
```

I tried adding "and" operators but that doesn't seem to work..

```
Me.tenant_QueryBindingSource.Filter = "address like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'" AND "number like '%'" & TextBox2.Text & "%'"
```

Comment: `And` should work, please show what you tried. -- The wildcard character in Access is `*`, not `%`.

Comment: Added it to the description. For some reason % did work though on visual studio 2019.

Comment: From `Me.` I assumed your frontend was Access.

Comment: Well, i access an Access database via a Form, the filter is placed on the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

`And` is part of the filter and so it must be part of the filter string:

```
Me.tenant_QueryBindingSource.Filter = "address like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' AND number like '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%'"
```

But filtering for numbers with `like` will probably not work, e.g. `2` will find also `123`.

So you'd rather use

```
Me.tenant_QueryBindingSource.Filter = "address like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' AND number = " & TextBox2.Text
```

Comment: okay, the query did indeed work! Thanks. Now I get the message `"System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String.' "`

Comment: If your "house number" column is a Number field, you can't search with LIKE. See edit.

Comment: Make sure you build a valid filter string, please post this string.

Answer (score 0):

You could first add an expression column to the datatable (DataSource of the bindingsource)
then run your like query filter on that column
IE:

```
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {
                   .ColumnName = "FullAddress",
                   .DataType = GetType(String),
                   .Expression = "address + ' ' + number"})

    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FullAddress LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```